# How to copy files from an ssh machine to my local pc?

Tags: server, ssh, file-sharing, sftp

I'm connected to a ubuntu linux box using `ssh -X 'username@institution'`

I'm confused on how to copy a file from the remote linux box to my local PC, say the Documents folder. I'll be transferring from Ubuntu -> Windows.

I'm aware of the

> sftp

command but I'm not sure how to use it to do this

Comment: The sftp works like the regular ftp.

Comment: Yes, but what is the command? It keeps looping back to ubuntu and won't download to my windows machine

Comment: What are you using for an SSH client? Clients like PuTTY and WinSCP have sftp functionality built in.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## Basic `sftp` tutorial

Use the command:

```
sftp username@institution
```

This will take you to the `sftp` prompt like:

```
Connected to institution.
sftp>
```

Now type help like this:

```
sftp> help
```

This will show you all the commands you can use at this prompt. Use the `get` command to download a file from the Ubuntu to Windows:

```
sftp> get mybigfile.txt
```

Finally use the `quit` command to return home:

```
sftp> quit
```

Here is [a more detailed tutorial](https://www.hostinger.com/tutorials/how-to-use-sftp-to-safely-transfer-files/)

Hope this helps